# Java AWT - alt press detected every other occasion

Tags: java, input, keyboard, awt

Consider test case for AWT frame where we print key press and release events

```
Frame frame = new Frame("Test");

frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released " + e);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed " + e);
    }
});

frame.setVisible(true);
```

in case of CTRL and SHIFT modifiers, everything goes as expected and press followed by release is detected. In case of AltGr is detected double press with alt, and double release (I could get over that, at least it is somewhat consistent and detectable), but in case of ALT with subsequent "types" press -> release -> release -> press -> release -> release are detected.

Entire event prints:

```
    pressed java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Alt,extModifiers=Alt,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
    released java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
    released java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
    pressed java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Alt,extModifiers=Alt,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
    released java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
    released java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
```

Except for `modifiers=Alt,extModifiers=Alt` on released events are identical.

Is there anything I can do to achieve consistent behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? I want to display UI options with key bindings that use alt modifier when alt is pressed, but that is not really possible when I cannot hide these options consistently.

I have seen some suggestions with SWT input maps, but AWT usage is unfortunately a must.

Checked behaviour on java 10 and java 8, it is the same, but there is indeed a difference between operating systems. A linux distro produces correct behaviour, while windows 10 and 7 do not. Now the question remains, whether it is bug or a feature.

**Edit 1:** Listed code was swing frame, fixed to AWT, it has no influence on the problem.

**Edit 2:** Fixed swapped release/pressed (no effect on essence of the problem)

Comment: Can I point out - your print statements are backwards, you're printing `pressed` on `released` ;)

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What OS are you using?  I had a issue while testing another question yesterday on Java 8 which wouldn't generate "press" events, but would generate "release" events in some scenarios, which was corrected by updating to Java 10. I've tried your example using Java 10 and don't seem to be able to replicate it

Comment: I'm on java 10, windows 10. Will try shuffle used JDKs around.

Comment: It could also be a Windows 10 based issue as I'm running macOS

Comment: It was indeed OS dependent. Not sure if it is JRE bug or windows API feature though ...